# Where is the parallelism concept here?

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix, multiplication

My teacher asked me to write a program that multiplies 2D matrices but using threads, and I can't find the benefit of using threads here! how can I divide the work between two threads? Can anyone explain to me what is the benefit of doing this, thank you!

Here is my code without threads
Actually, everything depends on each other, so I couldn't think of idea to split the work

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    out.println("Enter your first array rows");
    int r1=in.nextInt();
    out.println("Enter your first array cloumns");
    int c1=in.nextInt();

    double[][] m1=new double[r1][c1];

    out.println("Enter your second array rows");
    int r2=in.nextInt();
    out.println("Enter your second array cloumns");
    int c2=in.nextInt();

    double[][] m2=new double[r2][c2];

    if(c1 == r2)
    {
        out.println("Enter your first matrix numbers");
        for(int i=0;i<m1.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<m1[0].length;j++)
            {
                m1[i][j]=in.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        out.println("Enter your second matrix numbers");
        for(int i=0;i<m2.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<m2[0].length;j++)
            {
                m2[i][j]=in.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        double[][] product=multiply(m1,m2);
        for(int i=0; i<product.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<product[0].length;j++)
            {
                out.print(product[i][j] + " ");
            }
            out.println();
        }
    }
     else
    {
            out.println("Sorry you can't multiply these metrecies");
    }
 }

//A method for normal multiplication without threads

public static double[][] multiply(double[][] a,double[][] b)
{
    int aRows=a.length;
    int aColumns=a[0].length;
    int bColumns=b[0].length;

    double[][] c=new double[aRows][bColumns];
    for(int i=0;i<aRows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<bColumns;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<aColumns;k++)
            {
                c[i][j]=c[i][j] +  a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }

        }
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: By "2D metrics" do you mean "2D matrices"? Hint: ask yourself what dependencies there are between the different operations. If you had two 100x100 matrices to multiply together, and you had a small group of people, how would you divide the work up?

Comment: write out the logic for multiplying matrices and perhaps it may become more clear as to how multiple threads can help

Comment: Yes "2D matrices", actually I only have 2 matrices, so each line of code depends on the previous line, and I couldn't find a way to divide the work between 2 threads!

Comment: What code are you referring to?  You haven't shown any attempt.

Comment: @AndrewS I updated my question with the code, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

"each line of code depends on the previous line"

You should start not from the code, the code should be the result. Start with functional dependencies, where result of a function depends on its parameters. Find the functions to use. Represent the computing as a tree of function calls. Then parallel branches of that tree are candidates to parallel execution.

The matrix multiplication can be described as invocation of the famous function
[image]

which has to be called mxm times. Each such call is independent of other calls, so all invocations can be run in parallel.

Evidently, to create a thread for each separate invocation would be a bad idea because of too much overhead. Optimal way is to split the whole set of invocations in a set of larger jobs. Optimal number of jobs is equal to the number of processors in your computer. Cores and core threads are considered as separate processors.